# Does using Apache Basic Auth affect yum installations?

Tags: apache-2.2, yum, http-basic-authentication

I don't have further information yet, but I am going to be troubleshooting this in the morning and I wanted to get a head-start.  Is there any reason that a yum install (that worked fine yesterday) would fail after I set up basic authentication in Apache last night?  I have searched with google and SF for almost an hour and can't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that yum package is being retrieved from, or via that apache, then sure.

Check the apache logs to make sure that isn't the case.

Comment: You were right.  yum was connecting to another host to get updates.  I changed the auth to be at a more specific level and all was fine.  Thanks for attempting to help even though I gave insufficient info.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what did you "*yum install*"?

I can't really follow what the relationship beween your yum command, and an apache configuration is.

Comment: We are using yum to install a locally created package.  It was not anything related to Apache, and that is also why I am a little puzzled.

Comment: I can't immediatley see a link. What was the locally created package, and how does basic auth fail? anything in the logs?